# Modify array format in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am using the following array format. I have 2 userid's. I want to reform this array according to userids.

I have Below array in PHP :

```
Array
(
[808] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 1
        [3] => 1
        [4] => 0
    )

[766] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 0
        [3] => 0
        [4] => 1
    )
)
```

and i want it to be in below format :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [808] => 1
        [766] => 0
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [808] => 1
        [766] => 1
    )    
[2] => Array
    (
        [808] => 1
        [766] => 0
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [808] => 1
        [766] => 0
    )
[4] => Array
    (
        [808] => 0
        [766] => 1
    )

)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stackoverflow is not here to just give you the code, it is here to help you to understand how to do it.

Comment: This is not the actual array format . It was something different earlier but i have modified it to make it like this using foreach loop. But now i got stuck, i am not able to reform this array. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$array = Array
(
808 => Array
    (
        '0' => 1,
        '1' => 1,
        '2' => 1,
        '3' => 1,
        '4' => 0
    ),

766 => Array
    (
        '0' => 0,
        '1' => 1,
        '2' => 0,
        '3' => 0,
        '4' => 1,
    )
);

$result = array();

foreach($array as $key => $subarray)
{
    foreach($subarray as $subkey =>$subvalue)
    {
        if(!isset($result[$subkey]))
           $result[$subkey] = array();

        $result[$subkey][$key] = $subvalue;
    }
}


echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [808] => 1
            [766] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [808] => 1
            [766] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [808] => 1
            [766] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [808] => 1
            [766] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [808] => 0
            [766] => 1
        )

)
```

**Working example: [CLICK!](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0d4e5101cc73e8e293a4e7a5d50ed635220bf6a2)**

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
$ids = array_keys($your_array);
$new_array = array();
foreach($i=0; $i<count($your_array[0]); $i++){
    foreach($ids as $id){
      $new_array[][$id] = $your_array[$id][$i];
    }
}
```